# Amount of Breathable Air in a Depressurized Scuba Tank

Tags: pressure, air

The question: How long could a person survive in an airless chamber using only the oxygen released from a 100ft^3 tank containing 32% oxygen?

Long version:
 I'm doing a story on a man who allegedly survived under water for two days after his scuba regulator broke while exploring a wreck. He purportedly survived in an air pocket. This is a different situation than the Nigerian cook, previously discussed on this forum, who's air came with him since he sunk with his ship.
 We have been unable to locate the man--one Michael Proudfoot--and believe the whole story may be bogus. So, we're trying to mythbust various elements of it.

Here's where I need some help from people who understand the science of air much better than I do--I want to know, how long can you survive on air released from a compressed scuba tank into an airless chamber? Since a normal diver would be exhaling his air into the water, I can't go by how long a diver can stay under water with a tank (roughly 90 mins). In this situation, he would be exhaling oxygen back into the room, thereby recycling the content.
 Note, this is a separate question from CO2 poisoning, which I know would get a person sooner than oxygen depletion, but we're trying to work through every angle.

Here's the numbers I've been working with, but I'm a liberal arts guy, and Chaucer isn't being very helpful:

Assumptions:

-100ft^3 tank, that's unrealistically full at the time of depressurizing.

-Tank contains 32% oxygen, which is a normal mixture

-Oxygen loss is ~15L/hr, based on another site's math

-Asphyxiation happens when oxygen levels fall below 16%

Therefor:

-2831 liters of compressed air

-is 905 liters of oxygen (2831*.32)

-16% of which is 144

-leaving 761 liters of oxygen to breath before asphyxiation

-thus, 761/15L per hour loss= 50 hours of oxygen, which if true means a person could survive for two days, even if there was no oxygen in the air pocket aside from what was released from the tank.

This to me seems way too much, which is why I'm here asking for help. If it matters (does it?), let's assume the wreck is at 100ft (3 ATM), and his air pocket is 3x3x6ft.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "airless chamber"? What was in the chamber before the diver released his gas into it? It certainly wasn't empty space. Was the chamber full of water that was displaced by the gas from the tank? Or did it contain some other mixture of gas? It's important because the diver asphyxiates faster if their gas is diluted, e.g. due to mixing with whatever gas was in the chamber beforehand. The other important point is that asphyxiation occurs at (say) 0.16 atm O$_2$ partial pressure, which can constitute much less than 16% of the total gas mix at depth.

Comment: Another minor comment: the ambient pressure at 100 ft of seawater is approximately four atmospheres, not three: you have to include the pressure of all that air lying on top of the sea as well :)

Comment: And 32% oxygen is way too much - the canonical number is 20.95% in air, and standard SCUBA tanks are just compressed air.

Comment: @JonCuster 32% is a common [nitrox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrox) mix, often used in place of air to reduce the risk of [DCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompression_sickness) from nitrogen absorption. It does increase the risk of [oxygen toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity), which would not be a problem on a short dive at 100 ft but could become a very serious (i.e. fatal) problem after several hours.

Comment: @MarkMitchison - yes, it is common for nitrox. That makes it actually quite _uncommon_ for scuba writ large. So, if a professional diver, perhaps one could assume multiple tanks as well?

Comment: @JonCuster Um, well that really does depend. In certain scenarios even a recreational dive in very easy conditions could see a large proportion of nitrox users who are not "professionals". But you're correct that on a deep wreck penetration dive one should carry at least one additional cylinder, especially if diving alone which is what this guy must have been doing. On an unrelated note, there's a lot more about this story that doesn't add up: even if the diver survived 2 days at 30 m, they would have needed *several more days* to ascend to the surface without dying immediately from the bends!

Comment: Thanks for all the comments so far! The hard part here is that there are almost not details to go by. There's a good point here that the pocket could possibly have been just what was created by the air from the tank, which I suppose is what this question is asking--with that air alone, could someone breathe for 48 hours? Would it be helpful to take the situation out of the question, and ask instead if the air was released into a sealed, airless room, would that be enough for an average person to survive 48 hours?

Comment: @RobertCarver (You can tag people in comments like this, otherwise they don't see your messages.) That's fine, but it's extremely important to specify the size of the room. This should be intuitively obvious: if you find yourself in a sealed aircraft hangar with no air, emptying a single scuba cylinder into your environment is not going to help you much! In a sealed cupboard you might fare better. In my view it may be simpler to work backwards: assuming one cylinder of 32% nitrox and a given depth, what size of room does one need to avoid asphyxiation over a two day duration?

Comment: @MarkMitchison Thanks for helping me work through this! Working backwards does seem appropriate. Could you walk me through an appropriate equation, if you know it?

Comment: @RobertCarver yeah i'll have a go at solving this later today if i can find time

Comment: @MarkMitchison Wonderful, thank you! Appreciate the patience with my clunky handling of this, as well!

Comment: presence of mind would be the biggest factor. An anxious person who expends energy will metabolize O2 at a much higher rate than someone who can put themselves in a relaxed, meditative state. Also O2 supply is just *part* of the problem. Respiration leads to CO2. And without a CO2 scrubber or other means to ventilate the space, the levels can be high enough to lead to CO2 narcosis, and eventually death, before you reach the 16% O2 level. And if the person is not in tropical waters, even with a wetsuit - hyopthermia can kill.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Hi Mark, just checking if you've had a chance to run these calculations? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi @RobertCarver, sorry I haven't managed to find time yet, it's a pretty busy time for me at the moment. I should be able to write you up an answer this week.